# Download DT::datatable as pdf in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

Is it possible to download a `DT::datatable` as pdf through a `shiny` app ?

```
#app.r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(3,
      
      downloadButton(
        outputId = "downloader",
        label = "Download PDF"
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 3,
      dataTableOutput("table")
    )
    
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  
  #****************************************
  #* Reactive Values
  
  table <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })
  

  
  #****************************************
  #* Output Components
  
  output$table <- 
    renderDataTable({
      table()
    })
  
  
  
  #****************************************
  #* Download Handlers
  
  output$downloader <- 
    downloadHandler(
      "results_from_shiny.pdf",
      content = 
        function(file)
        {
          rmarkdown::render(
            input = "report_file.Rmd",
            output_file = "built_report.pdf",
            params = list(table = table()
                          )
          ) 
          readBin(con = "built_report.pdf", 
                  what = "raw",
                  n = file.info("built_report.pdf")[, "size"]) %>%
            writeBin(con = file)
        }
    )
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and

````
#report_file.rmd
---
title: "Parameterized Report for Shiny"
output: pdf_document
params:
  table: 'NULL'
---


```{r}
params[["table"]]
```
````

Comment: There's a `pdf` button in the `Buttons` extension. But the pdf it generates is not nice if the table is too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `pdf` button of the `Buttons` datatables extension. In this way you don't need a `downloadHandler`. Otherwise, below is a solution using the good old `xtable` package. For more sophisticated tables, use `kableExtra`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(xtable)
library(withr)
library(shinybusy)

ui <- fluidPage(
  add_busy_spinner(spin = "cube-grid", onstart = FALSE),
  column(
    width = 3,
    downloadButton(
      outputId = "downloader",
      label = "Download PDF"
    )
  ),
  column(
    width = 3,
    DTOutput("table")
  )
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  table <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })
  
  #****************************************
  #* Output Components
  
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(table())
  })
  
  #****************************************
  #* Download Handlers
  
  output[["downloader"]] <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "results_from_shiny.pdf",
    content = function(file){
      texfile <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file), ".tex")
      latex <- print.xtable(
        xtable(table()), print.results = FALSE, 
        floating = FALSE, scalebox = "0.7"
      )
      writeLines(
        c(
          "\\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}",
          "\\usepackage{graphics}",
          "\\usepackage{caption}",
          "\\begin{document}",
          "\\minipage{\\textwidth}",
          latex,
          "\\captionof{table}{My caption}",
          "\\endminipage",
          "\\end{document}"
        ),
        texfile
      )
      with_dir(
        dirname(texfile), 
        tools::texi2pdf(texfile, clean = TRUE)
      )
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: your solution does not work. I guess that it works at your end. May be a problem with package versions I use? Should I have something installed locally to make it work? Im facing the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490806/shiny-app-downloas-kable-in-rstudio-cloud-but-not-locally

Comment: I get : Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5103
Warning: Error in texi2dvi: unable to run pdflatex on 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeeOZ1V\file30f462e16a1.tex'
LaTeX errors:
! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.2 \usepackage
               {graphics}^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: @firmo23 Looks like you have to install [standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone).

Comment: could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654355/exclude-values-from-shiny-widgets-based-on-the-selection-of-the-same-values-from

Comment: could u check that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097631/dataframe-is-subseted-by-row-number-and-not-by-cell-value-after-clicking-on-dt